# Make eclipse CDT ignore errors on certain functions

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-mars

I program C++ applications which heavily use external libraries which are installed on the remote machine, and not on my local machine where I develop the code.

Is it possible to ignore errors on specific functions/classes, while still having eclipse show errors/warning for the rest of the code?I'm thinking of a functionality similar to "Add to dictionary" in spell checkers.

I use eclipse Mars 4.5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a simple solution for this:

I downloaded the header files (i.e. *.h files) from the remote machine where I have all the libraries installed. I put them all in a folder (named it external_libs), and then went to the

> project properties --> C/C++ General --> Path and Symbols --> Includes

and added that directory to the include path. Then rebuild the index (right click on project --> index --> Rebuild), and done.

Comment: This does not sound like a workaround but rather as it should work.

Comment: @JonahGraham You're right. Thanks. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Specific classes can be excluded from build, consequently ignoring errors in those. I don't think specific functions can be excluded that way. For more information on including/excluding selective classes in build, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28786322/how-do-i-use-build-run-configurations-in-cdt-using-eclipse-luna/28798214#28798214)

Comment: As far as I understood, this feature allows for including/excluding certain **source** class files, which is not what I want. In my case, the missing classes/function are actually **non-existent** on my local development machine. For example, let's say you don't have <iostream> installed on your local machine, but you're using it in your source code. I'm looking for a way to exclude all the function calls to std::cout or std::cerr.